# add new rule to my htaccess file to replace ? by /

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my htaccess file please take a look

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
 Options -Indexes 
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?brand=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

  ### rules to convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2 

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\? [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)&(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&=]+$
   RewriteRule ^(profile)\.php$ /$1/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE,R=302]

    # recursion rule to replace /n1/v1/n2/v2 to QUERY_STRING
     RewriteRule ^(profile)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1.php$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

      ### end of convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
     RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to add a new rule to this file which can replace this url **www.domain.com/profile?id=2** to **www.domain.com/profile/2**

i am new to htaccess please help me

and one important thing is that i should able to fetch the get variable fro id in my php code

```
 $idis=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=htaccess%20rewrite%20query%20string%20to%20path&es_th=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are getting pretty complicated. With that regex pattern and ordering has become much more important. Have your full .htaccess as this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?brand=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

### rules to convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\? [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [DPI,E=QS:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&=]+$
RewriteRule ^(profile)\.php$ /$1/%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE,R=302]

# recursion rule to replace /n1/v1/n2/v2 to QUERY_STRING
RewriteRule ^(profile)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1.php$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

### end of convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: dear sir, can you please please tell me how to replace all ? and = by / in the urls as there are many paces where i need to do this.

I am 100% you can tell me because are the best in htaccess file.
although your modification didnot helped me but yet i accepted the answer . because the answer is great and somewhat related to what i wanted ...

Comment: Rules below `rules to convert ?n1=v1&n2=v2 /n1/v1/n2/v2` are the ones I have posted in one of the answer on SO and that is what they do. Feel free to post a new question if it is not working for your for some reason. I will be happy to help you.

Comment: here http://www.reurl.in/c2967ca1f  sir i have added another question with other htaccess file .. it is not linked with this htaccess .. please take a look and please suggest me something

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/id/%1? [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/id/([^/]+)/?$ /profile/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: where should i place this code in the file above ... i mean at the begning or  at the end ??

Comment: this code dosent sends get data i can not receive the data received from GET variable

Comment: Your other rules are overwriting this, try adding this bellow the rewriterule => "###Rules to convert ?n=1...."

Comment: it says internal server error and alo it redirects to profile/1 i want it to be like profile/id/1